# Running program in Python [ActiveState Python on Windows]

Tags: python, activestate

I just started learning python and was writing programs in Python GUI Shell IDLE. The code is the following:

```
>>> def buildConnectionString(params):
    """Build a connection string from a dictionary of parameters.
    Returns string. """
    return ";".join(["%s=%s" % (k,v) for k,v in params.items()])
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        myParams = {"server":"mpligrim",\
                "database":"master",\
                "uid":"sa",\
                "pwd":"secret"
                }
        print(buildConnectionString(myParams))
```

I am facing a problem while I I try to run this program. In IDLE, when I click on Run Module,  a new windows opens up saying "Invalid Syntax"
Here's the screenshot:
[image]

I am not able to find how to run this and would appreciate the help in proceeding further with this.

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJZb1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `if __name__ == "__main__":` back by four spaces; your spacing in IDLE is different from that which you've copied and pasted here, the code works fine:

```
def buildConnectionString(params):
    """Build a connection string from a dictionary of parameters.
    Returns string. """
    return ";".join(["%s=%s" % (k,v) for k,v in params.items()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myParams = {"server":"mpligrim",\
        "database":"master",\
        "uid":"sa",\
        "pwd":"secret" }

    print(buildConnectionString(myParams))
```

Open up a new window in idle and create this as a .py script. Then press `F5` to execute, or go to run -> run module

Comment: You mean like this>> http://i.imgur.com/RjWQJ.png  ?
Still getting the same 'invalid syntax' error.

Comment: Your spacing is still slightly incorrect, the dictionary myParams has too many spaces for the rows after the first. You might want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for the `if` statement. It looks like you're trying to run it all on the shell, as you're not actually running a script the `if` won't work. Open up a new window in IDLE and copy this into there. Then run module ( `F5` ). It worked for me once the spacing has been changed, I've changed my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Phew! So much for just spacing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've copied the header output from a shell window into your module window:  You don't want your file to look like this:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> print "Hello World"
```

You just want this:

```
print "Hello World"
```

Delete all that other stuff.